# Can we replace login feature with Biometric authentication in iOS?

Tags: ios, authentication, touch-id

Is it possible to replace Login functionality (with username and password) to logging in with fingerprint/Face ID in iOS. I have read about LocalAuthentication framework from iOS but that just returns a "success" or "fail" message on authentication whereas in my case I want to map that with the person (user) who is logging in and have to display information specific to that user.

I have seen some solutions which suggest to save the user credentials in "NSUserDefaults" on first time login and then verify against that information after biometric login each time. But still don't know how we can achieve that since we don't save any information associated with a users biometric login.

Comment: initially the manual login needed,  then  we store the user name and password in keychain as well as store the user name in userdefault also, once success the Touch ID/faceID, we fetch the user name and password from keychain and call the api once success the navigate to another screen

Comment: @Anbu.karthik This can happen only if one user's finger print is configured in the device right ? Also is it correct to implement this since we don't tie up the user with his fingerprint/Face ID here ?

Comment: This can happen only if one user's finger print is configured in the device right ? -- yes, if not dont show the option then go with manual login

Comment: for example you can refer with paypal application,

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Okay will check that.

Comment: sure , but your ? is too broad to answer, if you need the help , i will support you

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I got the idea but is it the right way to implement this. Does Apple suggest this kind of an implementation ?

Comment: ya i did on my current app as well as payapal did this

Comment: The biometric authentication on iOS devices only indicates whether the supplied credential matches one of the enrolled credentials.  FaceID only allows the enrolment of a single credential (face) but multiple fingers can be enrolled for TouchID. You cannot use it identify which biometric credential (ie. finger) was used for TouchID.